# Why use get; and set; in a property without any arguments?

Tags: c#, get, set, setter, getter

I've been learning C# out of books recently and after explaining properties I notice them using properties like

```
public int AlertLevel { get; private set; }
```

and I can't figure out why you would do this without passing any arguments? Thanks for any info in advance.

Comment: Note the key word "private", changing the scope of what can set the property.

Comment: You very rarely want to pass arguments to a property. Maybe you're not clear on what properties are actually for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are actually methods in `C#`. And what you have shown in the code is  an [*auto-implemented*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property. It's a sytantic sugar for this:

```
// this backing field is generated by compiler
int alertLevel;

public int AlertLevel 
{
   get { return alertLevel; }
   private set { alertLevel = value; }  
}
```

And it's another syntactic sugar for this:

```
int alertLevel;

public int getAlertLevel()
{
    return alertLevel;
}
private void setAlertLevel(int value)
{
    alertLevel = value;
}
```

So you write less code, and you get same behaviour.That's the point.Compiler does the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

They're called auto-properties.  It's syntactic sugar.

It's the equivalent of:

```
private int alertLevel;
public int AlertLevel
{
  get { return alertLevel; }
  private set { alertLevel = value; }  
}
```

It allows the value to be accessed from other classes, but only set from within the class.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking how you'd just set the backing field directly, but you're right there's a distinction here and reasons you'd want to do it through the property instead (e.g. use of INotifyPropertyChanged).

Answer (score 0):

This is done to declare the element as an editable property with accessibility settings, hence the `private` declaration on set.  You can explicitly set `get;` and `set;` on any accessible property as well with the same effect.  This is simply a quicker way to type the full getter-setter relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The example you listed is actually pretty handy.  If you don't want other classes being able to modify this property, this is a lot easier than:

```
private int alertLevel;
public int AlertLevel
{
    get
    {
        return alertLevel;
    }
}
```

The other thing is the Designer view will recognize properties and expose them in IntelliSense.